Computing the posterior distribution in a Bayesian analysis of a normal linear regression model
Set up
We consider a normal linear regression model
$$
y = X \beta + \epsilon,
$$
where $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)^T\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T,$ $x_i=(x_{i1},\ldots,x_{ik})^T\in\mathbb{R}^k$, $\beta=(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k)^T\in\mathbb{R}^k$, and $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)^T$, $ \epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n\overset{i.i.d.}{\sim}N(0, v)$, $v>0$.
Let $X^TX$ be a regular matrix.
conjugate prior distribution
We assume
$$
\beta\mid v\sim N(0, vI_k),\ v\sim IG(a, 1/s).
$$
Problem
We want to show that the posterior distribution is
$$
\beta\mid v\sim N(\beta_0, vA),
$$
where $A:=(X^TX+I_k)^{-1},\ \beta_0:=A(X^Ty).$
Add:
and
$$
v \sim IG(a+n/2, (s^*)^{-1}),
$$
where $(s^*)^{-1}:=s+\frac{1}{2}(-\beta_0^TA^{-1}\beta_0+\|y\|^2)$.
What I know
By
\begin{align}
\pi(\beta\mid v)&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{k/2}\det(vI_k)}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\beta^T(vI_k)^{-1}\beta\right\}\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi v)^{k/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2v}\beta^T I_k \beta\right\},\\
\pi(v) &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\cdot\frac{s^a}{v^{a+1}}e^{-s/v}\ (v>0),\\
p(y,X\mid \beta, v) &= \frac{1}{(2\pi v)^{n/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2v}(y-X\beta)^T I_k (y-X\beta)\right\},
\end{align}
we get
\begin{align}
\pi(\beta\mid y,X; v) &\propto \pi(\beta\mid v)\cdot p(y,X\mid \beta)\\
&\propto \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2v}\left(\beta^T I_k \beta + (y-X\beta)^T (y-X\beta)\right)\right\}\\
&\propto\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2v}\left(y^Ty + \beta^TA^{-1}\beta-\beta^TX^Ty-y^TX\beta\right)\right\}\\
&\propto\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2v}\left(\beta^TA^{-1}(\beta-\beta_0)+y^Ty-y^TX\beta\right)\right\}\ \because -\beta^TX^Ty=\beta^TA^{-1}(-\beta_0)\\
&\propto \color{red}{\mathrm{I\ can't\ get\ the\ equation\ transformation\ here\ to\ work}}\\
&\propto \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2v}(\beta-\beta_0)^TA^{-1}(\beta-\beta_0)\right\}\ \mathrm{It\ should\ look\ like\ this}\\
\pi(v)&\propto \frac{1}{\Gamma(a+n/2)}\cdot\frac{s^{a+n/2}}{v^{(a+n/2)+1}}\exp\left\{-\frac{s}{v}-\frac{1}{2v}(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)\right\}\\
&\propto\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{v}\left(s+\frac{1}{2}(y^Ty-y^TX\beta-\beta^TXy+\beta^TX^TX\beta)\right)\right\}\\
&\propto \cdots
\end{align}
How should I calculate this?

Added in response to comment
\begin{align}
p(v\mid y, X)&= \int_\mathbb{R^n} p(\beta,v\mid y, X)d\beta\\
&\propto \frac{e^{-s/v}}{(2\pi v)^{(k+n)/2}(\det{A})^{k/2}}\int_\mathbb{R^n}\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\left((\beta-\beta_0)^T(\beta-\beta_0)+(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)\right)\right\}\\
&=\frac{\exp\{-s/v-(\beta^T_0\beta_0+y^Ty)/(2v)\}}{(2\pi v)^{(k+n)/2}(\det{A})^{k/2}}\int_\mathbb{R^n}\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\left(\beta^TA^{-1}\beta-2(\beta^T_0+y^TX)\beta\right)\right\}
\end{align}

Hi: No one responded so pages 1-22 of this provide all of the gory details. Zellner's text will also have them if you prefer a text. http://personal.strath.ac.uk/gary.koop/ec468_topic2_slides.pdf

Did you check the det part of $\pi(\beta \mid\nu)$ and of $p(y,X\mid\beta)$?

$\beta \mid \nu, y, X$
We only need to get that by a proportionality factor that is unimportant, i.e., anything not involving $\beta$ is unimportant. In other words, we don't need the "$=$" sign in every line, and "$\propto$" is sufficient.
So we can drop $y^Ty$ and add a $\beta_0^TA^{-1}\beta_0$ in the exponent for free, since neither has $\beta$. Also notice that $Y^tX\beta$ is the same as $\beta^TX^Ty$, or its transpose.
From there, completing the square is straightforward.

Added after the problem got updated:
$\nu\mid y,X $
(I'd not let $\pi(\nu)$ denote different things. See PS below.)
Here, $\nu$ is of interest and anything involving $\nu$ should not be dropped.

In the first line, you have dropped $\pi(\beta\mid\nu)$ that should be kept, because it has $\nu$ in it.

In the second line, you also dropped a $\nu^{-*}$ factor that involves $\nu$ (I believe you can figure out what $*$ should be).

The slightly harder part is the $\beta$ in the exponent. But you have learnt the trick in deriving $\beta\mid\nu,Y,X$, i.e., adding some quantity needed. But now since they share a denominator $2\nu$, while adding some thing, we also need to subtract the same thing.

Go back to the basics: If a joint distribution is given, how to find the marginal? We integrate out the unwanted variable. Here, it's the same. We have extra $\beta$ in the density of $\beta,\nu\mid y,X$ that we would like to eliminate, we can just integrate it out.

In the integration, which variable is of interest and what factors can be moved out of the integral?

The integration is easy once we realize the exponent is a quadratic form in $\beta$, as you have done in the derivation of $\beta\mid\nu, y,X$. Which distribution has this form? What constant factor is needed to make the integrand a bona fide pdf?



PS: It's better to pay attention to the notations in order remind oneself on which distribution I'm looking for, and which quantities are not of interest for this my specific purpose (distribution or integration, etc.):

In the goals, I'd prefer $\beta\mid\nu,y,X$ and $\nu\mid y,X$ over $\beta\mid\nu$ and $\nu$, respectively.

In the beginning "What I know" section, the $p(y,X\mid\beta)$ should be $p(y,X\mid\beta,\nu)$ and it should be $n$ rather than $k$ in it.

The "det" part in the first row $\pi(\beta\mid\nu)$ also needs to be double checked.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
